# Why Android Navigation Drawer is drawing back when clicked after making a layout Visible?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, navigation-drawer

**Introduction** 
   I am creating an Android App. It contains a navigation Drawer.

**My Problem** 
In my app , I am enabling the visibilty of a Relative Layout using onclick event. After the onclick event , the relative layout got visibilty.

Now the problem is , before enabling the visiblty of the relative layout "Navigation Drawer" working perfectly.

> But after the view got visible , The navigation drawer starts to draw
>   back when I click any menu item on the drawer. But before the view got
>   enabled , Navigation Drawer menu items respond perfectly

I cant figure out the problem. I used  `mDrawerLayout.bringToFront(); mDrawerLayout.requestLayout();` but not solution achieved

**My Code:**

**Map_Activity.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:keepScreenOn="true">


<RelativeLayout

    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/myCoordinator"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:id="@+id/map"
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            tools:context="com.cog.shyperDriver.Map_Activity">

        </fragment>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/onlinelay"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="150dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/custom_alert_corner"
                android:onClick="clickOnline"
                android:visibility="visible">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
                    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/onlineTxt"
                    android:background="@drawable/lock_outline" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/onlineTxt"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:text="@string/go_online"
                    android:textColor="@color/appColor"
                    android:textSize="15sp" />

            </RelativeLayout>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/onlineTxt1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:fontFamily="@string/app_font_regular"
                android:text="Home"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:visibility="gone" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/btmenu"
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                 android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/ic_menu"
                android:elevation="5dp" />


        </RelativeLayout>

        <!--</fragment>-->




    <!--current location -->
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/myLocationButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_gravity="top|end"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="200dp"
         android:background="@drawable/circle">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/myLocationImg"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:src="@drawable/gpsloc" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <!--bottom bar-->
    <com.roughike.bottombar.BottomBar
        android:id="@+id/bottomBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:bb_tabXmlResource="@xml/bottombars_tabs_three" />




</RelativeLayout>

<fragment
android:id="@+id/fragment_navigation_drawer"
android:name="com.cog.shyperDriver.adapter.FragmentDrawer"
android:layout_width="140dp"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_gravity="start"
app:layout="@layout/fragment_navi_drawer"
tools:layout="@layout/fragment_navi_drawer" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:id="@+id/offlineLayout"
    android:background="#fff">


    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/header"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10sp"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_menu"
            android:contentDescription="@string/todo"
            android:id="@+id/dialogMenu"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/footer"
        android:layout_below="@+id/header">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">


            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_margin="20dp"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                tools:ignore="UselessParent">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="200dp"
                    android:layout_height="200dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:src="@drawable/online_logo"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/todo" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
                    android:fontFamily="@string/app_font_medium"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:text="@string/you_are_offline"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:id="@+id/onoffstatus"/>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
                    android:fontFamily="@string/app_font_medium"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:text="@string/you_seems_to_be_offline"
                    android:textColor="@color/textcolor"
                    android:textSize="18sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
                    android:fontFamily="@string/app_font_medium"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"

android:text="@string/go_online_to_start_earning_right_away"
                    android:textColor="@color/textcolor"
                    android:textSize="18sp" />


            </LinearLayout>


        </RelativeLayout>
        <!--app:kswBackDrawable="@drawable/switch_bg"
        app:kswThumbDrawable="@drawable/switch_background_white"-->
    </ScrollView>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/footer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10sp"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_menu"
            android:visibility="invisible"
            android:contentDescription="@string/todo" />


    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

> In the above  code the layout with ID `offlineLayout` creating that
>   above mentioned problem after enabling visibilty .

Code that enables Layout visibilty:

```
public void showOfflineDialog(boolean isOffline) {

RelativeLayout offlineLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.offlineLayout);

if (isOffline)
{
    offlineLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    mDrawerLayout.bringToFront();
    mDrawerLayout.requestLayout();
}
else
{
    mDrawerLayout.bringToFront();
    mDrawerLayout.requestLayout();
    offlineLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}


}
```

> After enabling the `offlinelayout` , Navigation Drawer not responding to
>   clicks.. Simply Draws back.

**CodeBlock the initialise Navigation Drawer::**

```
    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

    drawerFragment = (FragmentDrawer)
          getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_navigation_drawer);
    drawerFragment.setDrawerListener(this);
```

Method handles OnClick events for the items in Nav Drawer

```
@Override
    public void onDrawerItemSelected(View view, int position) {


        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                Intent intent = new Intent(Map_Activity.this, YourTripsActivity_.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                break;
            case 1:
                Intent earnings = new Intent(Map_Activity.this, EarningActivity_.class);
                startActivity(earnings);
                break;
            case 2:
                Intent summary = new Intent(Map_Activity.this, EarningActivity_.class);
                startActivity(summary);
                break;
            case 3:
                Intent help = new Intent(Map_Activity.this, Help_activity.class);
                startActivity(help);
                break;

            case 4:
                logout();
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }


    }
```

> The above code responds perfectly before displaying offlineLayout ,
>   But failed to work after displaying offlineLayout

**Final Request** 
I tried hard to fix this problem , but I cant find any solution . Please help me.

Comment: Everything that is not the drawer should be inside one `ViewGroup`, and the drawer needs to be listed after that inside the `<DrawerLayout>` tags.

Comment: @MikeM. Issue Fixed. I followed the steps the you suggested. Thank you very much . You can add this comment as detailed answer , So I will help others

Comment: Thank you very much for saving my time @MikeM.

Comment: Actually, I'll just close this as a duplicate, 'cause it's been answered here several times before. Thanks, though. Glad you got it working. Cheers!